# SSL and Client Certificates

Tags: authentication, ssl, digital-certificate

An internal team, separate from my own, has stated that they prefer to do incoming authentication based on client certificates. Which sounds good to me, except that I haven't messed with them before and aren't quite sure where to start researching (Wikipedia went straight into a lot of detail that I'm not sure is pertinent to what I need to find out). If I have an IIS6 server with a web app that runs under an AD user account, what steps should I take to eventually fire off a request from that web app to a remote server, via .NET (I'm guessing HttpWebRequest)? I do see that we have an internal trusted certificate authority and all. Remote server is running Apache on Linux boxes.

I'm essentially in learning mode, not necessarily looking for a blow-by-blow list of what needs to happen (though if I could learn how it works while learning how to do it, that'd be nice too :)  ... **do you have any resources I could start looking into in order to figure out how to successfully authenticate securely via SSL with this remote server and communicate with it via client certs?** Probably from creation of the client cert on up, though I'd like to more fully understand how it all works in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315588. Hope this helps with what you are looking for.